# What does adiamorphic mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

While searching for words to substitute "godless" in [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/godless?s=t), I stumbled across that word. After searching in google for a while, I could not find any clear definition other than synonyms to this word, nor can I find the origins of this word. So, does it just mean no god? I reckon searching for synonyms often comes up with words close, but not quite similar to the exact definition of my query.

Comment: At a guess, *a•dia•morph•ic*: *not-god-shape-d*. Sounds like a modern, maybe lay, coinage. But this is all speculation.

Comment: I couldn't find it in any mainline dictionary.  I suspect it's either recent coinage as mentioned by Dan Bron or perhaps part of a joke.

Comment: I did find this: "Diamorph AB is a leader in the development and production of advanced materials."

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adiamorphic

Comment: http://definithing.com/define-thesaurus/adiamorphic/

Comment: Sounds like a word coined by someone who doesn't know their Latin from their Greek. It would actually be _a•dia•morph•ic: not-through-shape-d_, using @DanBron’s formula. _Dia-_ means ‘through’ in Greek (cf. _diaphanous_, _diabetes_, etc.), not ‘god’—that would be _theo-_. Considering that _diamorphine_ is an old term for heroin, _adiamorphic_ would presumably mean ‘heroin-free’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Given that Marx described religion as "the opiate of the masses", the etymology of _adiamorphic_ as a privative of _diamorphine_ (i.e. heroin, which is an opiate) seems plausible - it sounds like it might have originated from a Marxist with a sense of humour.

Comment: @Myles A Marxist with a sense of humour? Do such things exist?

Answer (score 2):

*Diamorphic* is defined as "Existing or occurring in two distinct forms; exhibiting dimorphism." by the OED, its etymology being: Greek δίμορϕος of two forms ( < δι-, δίς twice + μορϕή form) + -ic suffix.

So I would hazard a wild guess at *adiamorphic* meaning "not of two forms", and further suggest that it implies being of one form only.